# Minitest: How to test logic with empty table when fixtures exist?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

I have fixtures for a table 'Project' that creates a few entries in the table. It all works fine when I run tests that need the data to be in the table but I also want to run an Integrated test that tests the presence of some banner when there are no projects. The banner appears via javascript.

So, in my test, I run Project.delete_all before visiting the page. However, when the page loads, it still shows the projects that where created via the fixtures even if I removed them from the table. It is as if the test doesn't load from the table at all.

Here is my test:

```
  #   Given I am signed in
  #   And I am on the projects page
  #   When I have no projects
  #   Then I see a banner prompting me to create one
  scenario 'User sees prompt to create project', js: true do
    Project.delete_all

    visit projects_path

    page.must_have_content I18n.t('project.create_project.title')
  end
```

I use Minitest with Capybara and a selenium or poltergeist javascript driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most likely cause of this behavior is that you are removing the projects on the main thread, but Selenium is running on a different thread that hasn't had the projects removed. Each thread has its own database transaction, and so the changes you make on one thread won't be reflected on another thread.

I'd make sure you have something like this in your test_helper.rb file:

```
# Capybara driver
Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium

# Make all database transactions use the same thread
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool.class_eval do
  def current_connection_id
    Thread.main.object_id
  end
end
```

This will ensure that all database changes happen on the main thread.

Comment: Thanks! I realized that this was the problem and just found a different approach. Setting **self.use_transactional_fixtures = false** at the top of the test class also solves the problem. Instead of loading all the fixtures once and running the tests, it reloads the fixtures before each tests. So far, I have a negligible impact on speed. However, I am curious to know which approach is the recommended one. Yours or the use of the transactional flag?